# List items in Powershell edited last 4 years

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I need to have a list of all files paths (not only filenames), of all the files eidted in the last 4 years.
The file must have extension .xxx

I am trying this:

```
ls –recurse -filter *.xxx | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1460)}
```

This seems to work. However the results are not in the format I need:

```
    Directory: \\networkfolder\customerfolder


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       18.02.2019     10:23           1558 file.xxx
```

I would like a list with all the paths, such as:

```
18.02.2019     10:23           1558 \\networkfolder\customerfolder\file.xxx
18.02.2019     11:23           1558 \\networkfolder\customerfolder2\file.xxx
18.02.2019     11:23           1558 \\networkfolder\customerfolder3\file.xxx
```

How can I achieve that?
I am analyzing a huge list of thousands of folders with child folders so it has to be recursive and in a clean format for another person to easily go one by one to those network paths and do their job on those files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Select-Object` may help you. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6) for detailed information about it.

```
ls –recurse -filter *.xxx | where-object {$_.lastwritetime -gt (get-date).addDays(-1460)} | Select-Object LastWriteName, Length, FullName
```

Comment: Thanks, that's almost what I want, but it doesn't work for long file names:

`LastWriteName Length FullName
------------- ------ --------
                7179 \\longpath\hardware.xxx
                3208 \\longpath\hardware323523.xxx
                1558 \\longpath\sagsdgsdasdgdahsfgu...
`
For long filenames it appends 3 dots...
Any way to avoid that?

Comment: Thats because of the default formatting in Powershell. You've two options. Option1: You append  ` | Format-List` to the command in my answer. Option2: If you're running PowerShell 5.x on Windows, you can append `| Out-GridView`. If you want the content in a CSV-file you can append `| Convertto-CSV | Out-file temp.csv`. It's up to you.